# Create an empty pcolormesh in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can create an empty plot with

```
self.line, = self.axes.plot([],[], color="orange")
```

but when I try to do the same with pcolormesh

```
self.line2, = self.axes2.pcolormesh([],[],[])
```

I get a `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Are there any way to create the pcolormesh object with empty values? I'd like to add to data to the pcolormesh in other functions.

Comment: remove the comma after `self.line2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) returns a **list** of curves (as a list of [Line2D](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) elements).  This is so to be consistent when multiple curves are drawn. E.g. `ax.plot(x1, y1, 'r-', x2, y2, 'b-')` would return a list of two curves.  Therefore, a comma is needed to unpack the list (of one element) to get the curve of `ax.plot`.

[`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) only can draw one mesh (as a [QuadMesh](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh)), so it returns it without packing it into a list. A single element can't be unpacked, so no comma should be used. Further, `pcolormesh` needs a `C=` parameter to be a **2D** list (or numpy array). `pcolormesh` accepts two ways to provide the lists. Either as `pcolormesh(X, Y, C)` or directly as `pcolormesh(C)`. To distinguish between the two formats, the types and the dimensionality of these parameters need to be inspected, and empty lists can cause confusion there. The way to have an empty `pcolormesh` is to skip X and Y, and provide `C` as a 2D list:

```py
quads = plt.pcolormesh([[]])
```